# Unable to retrieve correct values from the JSON format. Assistance required

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need a little assistance in obtaining values from a JSON object in C#. Here is the code and the output. I am trying to retrieve value of `ScoreRepresentation` from both the objects. The obtained values in this case would be `BR400L` and `null` as per the below output.

Can anyone please assist? Newbie in C# :) Thanks in advance

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"Results\":[{\"RequestIdentifier\":\"Lexile\",\"ValueType\":\"INTEGER\",\"Scores\":[{\"lexile\":{\"ScoreValue\":-400,\"ScaledScore\":-400,\"ScoreRepresentation\":\"BR400L\"}}]},{\"RequestIdentifier\":\"UnifiedScaleScore\",\"ValueType\":\"INTEGER\",\"Scores\":[{\"unifiedScaleScore\":{\"ScoreValue\":610,\"ScaledScore\":610,\"ScoreRepresentation\":null}}]}]}";

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine(deserialized);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "RequestIdentifier": "Lexile",
      "ValueType": "INTEGER",
      "Scores": [
        {
          "lexile": {
            "ScoreValue": -400,
            "ScaledScore": -400,
            "ScoreRepresentation": "BR400L"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RequestIdentifier": "UnifiedScaleScore",
      "ValueType": "INTEGER",
      "Scores": [
        {
          "unifiedScaleScore": {
            "ScoreValue": 610,
            "ScaledScore": 610,
            "ScoreRepresentation": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi john, from a short look it looks ok. What is the actual issue you are having?

Comment: @Slipoch Hi, I am unable to fetch the values I need from this JSON.
Not sure what is the approach to be followed. I need to retrive `ScoreRepresentation` from above JSON so that I can use those values for further processing

Comment: some one told me to use `DeserializeObject<SomeModel>() ` but I don't know how to do that. Can you please assist?

Comment: the SomeModel part is a c# object tat should match your JSON object. Maybe do some tutorials on basic  C# first before trying to convert between formats. So if I create a model in C# (public/internal class) then I could deserialise the json into that model and it will match the json fields to the property names of the c# object and insert the values into them.

Answer (score 2):

I like to go the "Model" route. You create models of your data, then you can easily deserialize to them. Sometimes when I am feeling lazy, I will use [this site](https://json2csharp.com/) to do my work for me.

So, for your specific example, it gives back these models:

```
public class Lexile    {
    public int ScoreValue { get; set; } 
    public int ScaledScore { get; set; } 
    public string ScoreRepresentation { get; set; } 
}

public class UnifiedScaleScore    {
    public int ScoreValue { get; set; } 
    public int ScaledScore { get; set; } 
    public object ScoreRepresentation { get; set; } 
}

public class Score    {
    public Lexile lexile { get; set; } 
    public UnifiedScaleScore unifiedScaleScore { get; set; } 
}

public class Result    {
    public string RequestIdentifier { get; set; } 
    public string ValueType { get; set; } 
    public List<Score> Scores { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; } 
}
```

Then, you can simply deserialize to `Root` by doing this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Keep in mind that if your JSON is not perfect, you will find some inconsistencies with the output. You may have to massage your models a bit to fix those issues. You can't just assume that site gives you 100% accurate data.

But, if it's good enough, you can now get at every property you'd ever need to without having to putz around with dynamics or `JToken`.

For example:

```
foreach(var r in deserialized.Results)
{
    foreach(var s in r.Scores)
    {
        Console.Write(s.unifiedScaleScore.ScoreRepresentation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for throwing out a dump question, Andy
But Let's say I wanna access `ScoreRepresentation`. How should I be doing that using these models? Can you throw out the exact `line/Code` for me ?

Comment: @John -- updated answer. You seem pretty new to C#. You are kind of jumping in to the deep end here. I would suggest slowing down and learning some basics first... This is more of an intermediate problem to solve.

Comment: @John use this answer, it's a good comprehensive model based on your JSON.

To access sub objects you would use the above then go with deserialized.Scores.ElementAt(index int of element you wish to use)